# Should I replace a punctured tire immediately?

Tags: tire, puncture

Was going on my morning ride and unfortunately 5km away from my place my rear was punctured by a small nail and the hole is about 1mm wide. I patched up the innertube and mounted it on again and rode home, not sure if I should buy a new tire or I can cover it up with smth in the inside if it's still fine to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really depends on the size of the hole and how much puncture risk you are willing to take.

As long as there is no bulging around the hole and the tyre is keeping its shape it should generally be safe to use i.e. you don’t risk a sudden, catastrophic rupture of the whole tyre.

You can put something on the hole from the inside. There are special tyre boots but you can also use an inner tube patch. Even multiple layers of duct tape should help.

Comment: Thanks for answering! There's no bulge and it isn't deformed as far as I can observe but I'm gonna check it every once in a while just to be sure. Gonna use the duct tape because I know that won't be going anywhere.

Comment: Tyre boots and imitators such as duct tape are only for temporary use, and are needed only when there is bulging.

Comment: @juhist: They should also work fine to plug a hole to prevent pieces of sharp gravel puncturing your inner tube. I’ve tried filling holes with glue in the past, but it doesn’t hold up.

Comment: It's all an ongoing experiment for us all... Try leaving it, try some tape, try a  boot. From my experience, it sounds like you'll be fine without anything, tape won't hurt, boot may result in a slight increase of  rolling resistance ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯